# Unable to list "Date" from a datetime column on SQL server with retool

Tags: sql, sql-server, retool

I am unable to list "Date" from a "datetime" column on SQL server with Retool. I've tried using the 4 below variations in Retool and I can't see any row appearing in the preview for Retool. Can someone advise what i am doing wrong? I'm using Retool's date selector to specify the date.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Log WHERE dbo.Log.DateTimeEntry = {{ date2.value }}

SELECT * FROM dbo.Log WHERE dbo.Log.DateTimeEntry = {{ date2.value + '%' }}

SELECT * FROM dbo.Log WHERE dbo.Log.DateTimeEntry LIKE {{date2.value}}

SELECT * FROM dbo.Log WHERE dbo.Log.DateTimeEntry LIKE {{ date2.value + '%' }}
```

Comment: Why the Javascript tag?

Comment: @0stone0 I'm trying to display all related data in a table based on the date selected in retool date component. How else do I reference {{date2.value}} ? The extra JS is me trying to allow for everything beyond just the date in the SQL Table. My datetime writes like 2022-09-01T00-00 etc... So I'm trying to remove the time part and only display the date.

Comment: What are the actual data types involved? `DateTimeEntry` suggests that it's a `datetime` column, i.e.: it's storing a date along with time-of-day: `2022-09-01T13:12:11.567`.  If `date2` is just a date, for example `2022-09-01`, then it's only going to match `datetime` values that happen to be exactly `2022-09-01T00:00:00.000`.